# having problem adding membber in mailchimp error 400

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mailchimp-api-v3.0

currently on a beginner course and the teacher taught a way to send member data to mailchimp using nodejs have been stuck in the problem for long enough. does anyone spot the error ?
here is the code

```
const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require ("body-parser");
const request = require('request');
const https = require("https");

const app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

app.get("/",function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/signup.html");
})
 
app.post("/",function(req,res){

    var firstName = req.body.fName;
    var lastName = req.body.lName;
    var email = req.body.email;

    const data ={
        members:[{
            email_address : email,
            status : "subscribe",
            merge_fields:{
                FNAME : firstName,
                LNAME : lastName
            }
        }]
    };

    const jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
    const url = "https://us21.api.mailchimp.com/3.0/lists/aa5cf6a915";

    const options = {
        method:"POST",
        auth:"dineman1:d38cc7377bd5004fe4d5cf836a2eed65-us21"
    };

    const request = https.request(url,options, function(response){

        response.on("data",function(data){
            console.log(JSON.parse(data));
        });
    });

    request.write(jsonData);
    request.end();

});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("server is hosted on post 3000");
})
```

Please do teach me if there is another way to do it.sorry if my code is inconvenient to read its my first post and do share tip to improve my quetions ty

Answer (score 0):

I can't see any errors though but I think you need to check the statusCode of your response to deploy it in the web. Also you need to update your port from static to dynamic to host your app in web.

Response.statusCode :-

```
const request = https.request(url, option, function(response) {
        response.on("data", function(data){
            if(response.statusCode === 200){
                res.sendFile(__dirname + "/success.html");
            }
            else{
                res.sendFile(__dirname + "/failure.html")
            }

        console.log(JSON.parse(data));

        })
    })
```

and app.listen as :-

```
app.listen(process.env.PORT || 3000, function(req, res){
console.log("App is running on port 3000!")
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: TY for your ans Rohan. found out the error was on the request, it was invalid so i added / on the end of the url and it got sovled.

Comment: Okay Dinesh. Happy to help you 